# Wordpress (3.4.2) Pagination Issue - Custom Post Type

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

I've ran into a problem where I can't seem to get pagination to work on the latest wordpress version 3.4.2. I have developed a lot of wordpress sites so this rather confusing. I've got a custom post type of news, I wish to show 8 posts per page and the page url would be '/news'. This page displays correctly with the right pagination at the bottom (using WP-pagenavi). When I click on the second page (/news/page/2) I get my 404 page. I'd really appreciate any help on resolving this.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container_12">

   <div class="grid_12 box">            

        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'paged' => $paged);    
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="news">
                <h4><?php the_title() ?></h4></a>
                <span><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span>
                <p><?php limit_excerpt("30"); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>


        <div id="pagination">
            <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { 
                wp_pagenavi( array(
                    'query' =>$loop   
                )); 
            }
            ?>
        </div>

   </div>

</div><!-- .container_12 -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**[Update - Solution]**

So I've coded a solution for this. Put this in the functions.php

```
//Set for cpts
function cpt_init( $cpt )
{
add_rewrite_rule(
    "{$cpt}/page/([^/]+)/?",
    "index.php?pagename={$cpt}&pag=$matches[1]",
    'top' );
}

//Only Add Once
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cpt_query_vars' );
function cpt_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
 $query_vars[] = 'pag';
return $query_vars;
}

//Add for each type
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_init', 'news' );
```

And in your loop use `get_query_var('pag')` instead of `get_query_var('page')`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using global variable $paged instead of attributing it your own value ?

This is for example what is used in a cutom theme :

```
<?php
    global $paged;
    $the_query = new WP_Query();
    $the_query->query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=14&post_status=publish&paged='.$paged);
?>
```